# plot.CA() renders in shiny app locally but not when app is deployed

Tags: image, shiny, rendering

I have created a Shiny app that takes user input and creates a CA plot. It works just fine when I run the app locally, but for some reason when I deploy the dashboard, the image of the plot won't appear. I can see in the logs that the data uploading and reformatting into a proper data frame is working just fine, but the plot itself is failing to render.

Does anyone know why this might be? I posted my code below (you'll see some print() lines in my code that was used for debugging). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    #PERCEPTUAL MAPPING DASHBOARD

library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
library(SensoMineR)
library(shinythemes)
library(ca)



ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Perceptual Map Dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
    sidebarPanel(

      #Excel doc row and column names
      numericInput(inputId="startcol",label="Input start column of CSV file:",value="", min=1,max=10000),
      numericInput(inputId="endcol",label="Input end column of CSV file:",value="", min=1,max=10000),
      #Inputing brands and emotions
      br(),
      numericInput(inputId = "rownums",label = "How many emotions/characteristics are you evaluating?",value = "", min = 1,max = 10000),
      br(),
      h6("Note: Please enter brands and emotions/characteristics in the order that they appear in the excel document exported from Survey Gizmo."),
      textInput ( 'brands', 'List the brands included in your perceptual map (separated by commas):', value=""),
      textInput ( 'emotions', 'List the emotions/characteristics included in your perceptual map (separated by commas):', value=""),
      #Removing brands and emotions

      #Select graph type
      textInput(inputId="plottitle",label="Title your graph:"),
      #Upload Excel Grid
      fileInput(inputId = 'data', 'Upload CSV File',
                accept=c('.csv')),
      actionButton("go","Create Map")
    ),

    # Visual Output
    mainPanel(
      wellPanel(h4('Visual'),
                h5("Once your visual appears, just right click it to save it as a .png file.")),
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot",  width = "100%", height=500)
      # downloadButton("downloadPlot", "Download Visual")
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input,output){



  K <- eventReactive(input$go,{


      x <- read.csv(input$data$datapath, header = F)

      x[!is.na(x)] <- 1
      x[is.na(x)] <- 0
      x<-x[,as.numeric(input$startcol):as.numeric(input$endcol)]
      column.sums<-colSums(x)
      print(column.sums)
      pmd.matrix<-matrix(column.sums, byrow = T, nrow=as.numeric(input$rownums))
      pmd.df2<-as.data.frame(pmd.matrix)
      colnames(pmd.df2) = unlist(strsplit(as.character(input$brands),","))
      print(pmd.df2)
      row.names(pmd.df2)= unlist(strsplit(as.character(input$emotions),","))
      print(pmd.df2)
      pmd.df2[-nrow(pmd.df2),] 
      print(pmd.df2)
      fit <- CA(pmd.df2, graph=F)
      return(fit)


    })

  p <- eventReactive(input$go,{

      input$plottitle

  })

  output$plot<- renderPlot({

      plot.CA(K(), col.row = "blue", col.col="black",  cex=1, new.plot=T,
                    title=p())


  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't have the necessary packages to test this. One thing i can suggest however: Don't use `renderPlot` inside `observeEvent`. Instead, create a `eventReactive` that returns `pmd.df2`.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thanks for taking the time to review. I tried making that change but it still doesn't seem to work. Is it possible I did it incorrectly?

Comment: Your modifications look good. I really can't tell you what is going wrong there. One thing you might try is to save the file with `png()` and use `renderImage` to load it in the ui. That is basically what `renderPlot` does in the background but this way you can check if the image files are actually created.

Comment: So, things that I have now tried: 1) Changing from observeEvent to eventReactive (as seen above) and moving the renderPlot outside. 2) Saving this file as an image and calling the image 3) Saving my function to a variable called "o" and calling a print(o) after it. #3 is the closest I have gotten. What that does is it presents a white box the same dimensions of the plot I've requested, but it appears blank. Any other ideas?

Comment: So the images are created properly but `renderImage({list(src = imagepath)})` does not work? Am I right to assume you use `shiny-server` on an ubuntu server?

Comment: No not on Ubuntu actually. I just run them locally from my work laptop. I did not try writing the code just as you have above. I'm new to render image, but I used the shiny documentation to guide me and that still gave me trouble. It just produced a blank white plot. For whatever reason, the plot itself is failing to render, even if there is an image present.

Comment: I included syntax for `renderImage` in my answer below. If `renderImage` really fails to fetch `png` files the way you describe, the issue is probably not related to the five packages you use in your example.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest to you is to check whether this issue is specific to your plot or if `plot.CA` is not working with shiny in general. Try to "deploy" (apparently, you don't use a webserver?) the following app

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(shiny)

data(children)
res.ca <- CA(children, col.sup = 6:8, row.sup = 15:18)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(plotOutput("plot")),
  function(input, output, sesison) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot.CA(res.ca)
    })
  }
)
```

If this does work, there might be something wrong with your model or maybe there are name collusions between the `ca` package and the `FactorMineR` package.

If this  does not work, try the following instead

```
## use same data/libraries as above

myfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(imageOutput("plot")),
  function(input, output, sesison) {
    output$plot <- renderImage({
      png(file = myfile)
      plot.CA(res.ca)
      dev.off()
      list(src = myfile)
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  }
)
```

And see

1. Whether the app works now
2. Whether `myfile` gets created and contains reasonable contents.

Comment: So the first block of code you provided worked. I will go back and check my model. I am confused though because not only have I made this model work before with the same CSV and my list of input values (names of columns and rows), but the app also works locally and can produce the image with no problem. It's not until it gets published that it stops working, which leads me to believe that the issue might be more related to the plot.CA() function not recognizing the reactiveValues once it's deployed. Thoughts? And by the way, thank you for your help with this!